# Need to call a Method when we Zoom into the Map

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a MapKit based application. I had a problem in that, my problem is when we zoom into the map I need to call a method. I have no idea to get implement this one. Can you guys please help on this.

Thanking you,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with the MapKit before, but it follows Apple's Delegate Pattern.

You'll want to implement the delegates described in Apple's [LocationAwarenessProgramGuide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW4)

To check for a zoom, the region you're moving to should be smaller than the region you just viewed.  Then, just call the method you need to.